# RPG Maker MV - Left Handed Weapon is classed as Armour

Tags: rpgmakermv

I have recently been using RPG Maker MV to set up some weapons and mechanics for my own RPG project. I created a new equipment type which I named 'L.Hand' for left hand. I want the player to be able to equip a weapon or shield in this slot however it has appeared as an armour slot, not a weapon slot.

[image: Click here to view image!]

If anybody knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated if you could let me know.

Many Thanks,

Tommy Eaves

Comment: Just out of interest, what does a left handed sword look like?

Comment: It's just the same as a normal sword - I wanted to add left handed weapons so you could duel wield any combo of weapons

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have renamed an armor type, only the first equipment type is a weapon slot. As far as I can tell, normal RPG Maker doesn't support having multiple weapons, you'll have to use a plugin.

Download [this](https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?threads/equip-slots-core.50348/), and save it to the plugin section of your game's javascript files: Documents/Games/projectname/js/plugins/

Then go to the plugin section of the program and add the new plugin.

Afterwards, the actor's Initial Equipment section becomes useless, you will need to instead use the notes section to provide them.

```
<equip slot: Weapon>
<equip slot: Weapon>
<equip slot: Shield>
<equip slot: Head>
<equip slot: Body>
<equip slot: Accessory>
```

This should enable the use of multiple weapons, and you can remove one if you don't want that actor to have that equip slot.

Remember to do this to *all* of your actors, since it won't do this on its own.

I hope this has been helpful, hopefully you don't object to esoteric plugins like this.

Edit: look at the info for the plugin for further instructions and information.